# On the Product Structure of Spacetimes after Compactification

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, string-theory, compactification

I am currently looking into the compactification of spacetimes as it is often done in (super-)stringtheory.

So, say I start with a ten-dimensional Lorentz manifold $(N, g)$, where $N$ denotes the underlying smooth manifold and $g$ denotes the Lorentzian metric on $N$. 
Compactification would then lead to a ten-dimensional Lorentz manifold $(\widetilde{N}, g_{\widetilde{N}})$ that decomposes into product of a four-dimensional Lorentz manifold $(M^4, g_M)$ and a six-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(C^6, g_C)$.

My questions pertains to the Lorentzian metric $g_{\widetilde{N}}$ of $\widetilde{N}$.

**Is $(\widetilde{N}, g_{\widetilde{N}})$ assumed to be a direct product manifold or are people also interested in warped products as compactified spacetimes?**

By a warped product I mean the following construction:
Let $(M, g_M)$ and $(N, g_N)$ be two semi-Riemannian manifolds and let $f\in C^\infty(M, \mathbb{R}_+)$. Then the *warped product of $(M, g_M)$ and $(N, g_N)$* is the following semi-Riemannian manifold:
$M\times_f N :=(M\times N, g_M + f^2g_N)$.
The direct product is obviously a special case of the warped product where $f\equiv 1$.

I'd love to know whether warped products are being considered by physicists working with compactifications at all or not and of how much interest they are compared to direct product compactifictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Warped compactifications", often phrased in the language of a "non-constant dilaton", have been investigated but are probably not of great general interest due to no-go results that state that only the trivial warp factor can preserve supersymmetry like in [*"A no-go theorem for string warped compactifications"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008232) by Ivanov and Papadopoulos, which also contains a nice overview over some of the history of warped compactifications starting with Strominger's [*"Superstrings with torsion"*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321386902865).